# extract object names from sql query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to extract object names (table names, stored procedures, views and so on) from sql query, using sql server.
Is there any sql statement or keyword, or system stored procedure that can help with this task?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want a list of the names of the objects in the database?

That would be `select * from sys.objects`

Comment: I have a query: "select * from mytable where condition = true; execute my_storedprocedure 1,2,3"
What I'm willing to have is
DB_Object   | Type
---------------------------
my_table    | table
my_storedp..| stored procedure
and so on

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Tokenizer](http://search.cpan.org/~izut/SQL-Tokenizer-0.19/lib/SQL/Tokenizer.pm) - it splits your query on separate parts ("WHERE CLAUSE", "FUNCTION" etc.)

I guess you can use any other tool, but the general approach is to tokenize your query.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to solve this one, but each can be different depending on the version of SQL server you're on.

One of the lowest levels to extract this info from is sysobjects...

```
SELECT o.name,
CASE o.type 
WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table' 
WHEN 'V' THEN 'View'
WHEN 'P' THEN 'Procedure'
WHEN 'FN' THEN 'Function'
ELSE o.Type
END as Type
FROM sysobjects o
WHERE type in ('U', 'V', 'P', 'FN')
ORDER BY Type
```

This will work on just about any version of SQL Server.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of objects. Just similar to Paul Answer.

SELECT name,
           type_desc,
           type,
           create_Date,
           modify_date
    FROM   sys.objects
    ORDER  BY type_Desc,
              type,
              name